# How to order search results with related to slop in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I have an index in ES:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/so/_settings?pretty=true'

{
  "so" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "provided_name" : "so",
        "creation_date" : "1594912442805",
        "analysis" : {
          "analyzer" : {
            "my_simple_analyzer" : {
              "type" : "simple",
              "tokenizer" : "lowercase"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "8YVu4zU_Sdylr3KhOIwu9Q",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "7080099"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It has around 1.5M data.

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/so/_count?pretty=true'
{
  "count" : 15426942,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  }
}
```

I wanted to perform a full text search, so that the query string first does the phrase match and then followed by results which has slop of 1, then slop of 2 and so on.

So I came up with the below query for the same:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/so/_search?pretty=true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "posts": {
              "query": "get the scanner on a specific family like this",
              "_name": "exact_match"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "posts": {
              "query": "get the scanner on a specific family like this",
              "_name": "partial_match"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

Is this the correct query? Because I do see the `partial_match` doesnt sort from slop of distance 1 and so on. How to achieve it?